# Kivy, создание скролл ленты text+image

Tags: python, kivy

я бы хотел вместо надписей сделать фото и описание(что-то типо как в соц сетях лента). в  дальнейшем хочу взаимодействовать после нажатия на 'пост

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDIcon, MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import NavigationLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button

screen_helprt = """
Screen:
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Avtobot'
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
                        right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: app.callback()], ["filter-outline", lambda x: app.callback()]]
                        elevation: 10
                    Widget:
                


    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Поиск разборщика'

                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Профиль'
                    
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Мои заявки'
                    
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Избранное'
                    
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Настройки'
 

"""



class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()

        sv = ScrollView()
        ml = MDList()
        sv.add_widget(ml)
        contacts = ["BMW"]*100
        for c in contacts:
            ml.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=c))
        
        screen.add_widget(sv)
        
        plus_button = MDFloatingActionButton(icon='plus', size_hint=(None, None), opposite_colors=True, pos_hint={'center_x': .9, 'center_y': .1})
        screen.add_widget(plus_button)

        screen.add_widget(Builder.load_string(screen_helprt))
        
        return screen


Main().run()
```